# Universal selector or body selector

Tags: css

I am kind of confused between universal selector and body selector now because I need to add

```css
box-sizing:border-box;
Padding:0;
Margin:0;
```

Where should I keep this in universal selector or in body selector ?? Please clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

body selector will add those property to the `<body>` tag.

```
body{
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  Padding:0; 
  Margin:0;
}
```

But universal selector * will apply those properties in each element of the html content. if the structure is like this.

```
<body>
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
</body>
```

when you apply

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  Padding:0; 
  Margin:0;
}
```

It'll be applied to each element. like this -

```
body, h1, p{
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  Padding:0; 
  Margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother 